# When does changing a sub-array update the sub-array vs. creating a new sub-array? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a **[Edit: JavaScript]** code that uses a sub-array `dataSelectedArray` that tracks from my main data set `mainArray`.  The main data is stored as an array of arrays.

```
mainArray = [ [1,2,3],[3,4,2],[5,1,0] ];
dataSelectedArray=[];
for (var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
    if ( someLogic ) {
        dataSelectedArray.push(mainArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Thus, `dataSelectedArray` holds pointers to the values stored by `mainArray`.  Later, I need to update `mainArray` by replacing it with data from `updatedData`.    I need `dataSelectedArray` to also be updated.  I can think of two ways to do this: update each mini-array as a set, or update each component.

```js
var mainArray = [ [1,2,3],[3,4,2],[5,1,0] ];
var dataSelectedArray=[];
for (var i=0; i<mainArray.length; i++) {
    if ( i<2 ) {
        dataSelectedArray.push(mainArray[i]);
    }
}
 
updatedData = [ [ 1,0,0],[7,4,2] ];
for (var index= 0; index < updatedData.length; index++) {
    // this doesn't update dataSelectedArray
    mainArray[index] = updatedData[index];
}
console.log(mainArray[0]);
console.log(dataSelectedArray[0]);
```

```js
var mainArray = [ [1,2,3],[3,4,2],[5,1,0] ];
var dataSelectedArray=[];
for (var i=0; i<mainArray.length; i++) {
 if ( i<2 ) {
  dataSelectedArray.push(mainArray[i]);
 }
}
 
updatedData = [ [ 1,0,0],[7,4,2] ];
for (var index= 0; index < updatedData.length; index++) {
 // this *does* update dataSelectedArray
 mainArray[index][0] = updatedData[index][0];
 mainArray[index][1] = updatedData[index][1];
 mainArray[index][2] = updatedData[index][2];
}
console.log(mainArray[0]);
console.log(dataSelectedArray[0]);
```

The first method doesn't update `dataSelectedArray`...why not?  And is there a shorter (one-liner) way to do the second method?

Comment: Doesn't look like c# array

Comment: This is not a C# code. Either update the tag or the code (it should at least be compilable).

Comment: This is C#, using data that's from JS.  I've been transitioning between the two, so my object came from a JavaScript array, which explains the format.

Comment: @user203212546  `This is C#. ` No it is not...

Comment: It's not valid C# code at the moment. Consider cleaning up the code, otherwise the only valid answer to your question is that the code doesn't work as intended because it doesn't compile in the first place.

Comment: And now I feel silly.  I'm sorry.  I've been code-switching so much that I actually **WAS** in my JS file, and the updated data was parsed as a JSON from my C# file...so you guys are correct, it's JS.  Will update the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
dataSelectedArray.push(mainArray[i]);
```

`dataSelectedArray` contains a reference to the sub-array. This is *not* a reference to the location in `mainArray` where the original reference came from. So reassigning `mainArray[i]` has no effect on the value in `dataSelectedArray`.

It's no different from when you have multiple variables referring to the same array:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a; // a and b now refer to the same array
b[1] = 6;
console.log(a[1]); // Outputs 6
b = [7, 8, 9]; // b now refers to a different array
console.log(a[1]); // Still 6 -- a hasn't been modified
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Thank you.  Do you know of a better (shorter?) way to update the values of the sub-arrays, rather than assigning each value individually?

Comment: No, I don't know of a shorter way to do it. Define a function, then you can do `replace_array(mainArray[index], updatedArray[index])`